# Save layers and auto save: QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, save

When I save the shapefiles and the project the shapefiles do not save so I loose a lot of work every day. The problem starts when qgis starts to delay the save of the layers after long time in edit mode, so at the end of the day I save the project and the layers and the next day I don't have the last information in the layers that I saved. I have also set up the auto save for the 30 minutes but still doesn't save. What is the problem? I think it is the cache information. I am using qgis is 2.18.18.

Comment: Just a thought, something to explore, may be it is a network issue if you are trying to write to a network drive? Something to do with permissions maybe?

Comment: Qgis delaying saving layer edits is a symptom of a badly written plugin which you have installed. Try disabling all plugins and retest.